# Como altero a velocidade da transição (efeito) Fade? (código abaixo)

Tags: transição

Segue código que estou usando, vale citar que está funcionando 100%, apenas não consigo (e quero muito) alterar a velocidade do efeito Fade.

Segue Código:

```
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .item {
    -webkit-transition-property: opacity;
    transition-property: opacity;
}
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .item,
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .active.left,
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .active.right {
    opacity: 0;
}
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .active,
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .next.left,
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .prev.right {
    opacity: 1;
}
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .next,
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .prev,
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .active.left,
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .active.right {
    left: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
.carousel-fade .carousel-control {
    z-index: 2;
}
html,
body,
.carousel,
.carousel-inner,
.item:nth-child(1) {
    background: white;
}
.item:nth-child(2) {
    background: white;
}
.item:nth-child(3) {
    background: white;
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17332431/how-can-i-control-the-speed-that-bootstrap-carousel-slides-in-items

Comment: Não sofreu alteração, continua na mesma.

Existe alguma linha especifica para colocar os dados que vc sugeriu, Leo?

Comment: Também não sei, só traduzi esse link e me pareceu que ia resolver seu problema

Comment: sua pagina está online, pode passar o link?

Comment: A página está armazenada na maquina local, e não na net.